# Zend Framework Route issues

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I have created a Route in ZF as shown below.

```
   /** $Router->addRoute("artistprofile", new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                                    "artist/:name",
                                    array("controller" => "artist",
                                    "action" => "profile"
                                    )));
  */
```

the problem that I am facing is that all my actions in my artist controller end up being redirected to the profile.phtml action page.  For example I have an action in my artist controller called new which points to the new.phtml page and shows a signup form and I can access it like this 127.0.0.1/artist/new but only when the above code is not added as soon as I add the above code back into my script then 127.0.0.1/artist/new shows the profile.phtml page but does not redirect the user and it's the same for all my actions in the artist controller they show the contents of the profile.phtml file this is not meant to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if the Zend Router is working as it should be, all calls to 127.0.0.1/artist/name are being directed to default/artist/profile with the parameter name.  The call to 127.0.0.1/artist/new is simply taking the parameter new as the artists name.  If you want any calls to 127.0.0.1/artist/new to goto default/artist/new then you will need to add another route to do this.

```
$Router->addRoute("artistNew", new Zend_Controller_Router_Route( "artist/new", array("controller" => "artist", "action" => "new" )));
```

Kind regards

Garry

Comment: Hi Garry, Thanks for your help I have added the extra route but it still does not work? any Ideas

Comment: You could try putting the artistNew route before your artistprofile route.

Comment: Hi Garry Did that still no joy :(

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I am comming to the end of my Zend Routing knowledge here.  One other thing you could try is using Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static instead of Zend_Controller_Router_Route in the artistNew route.

Comment: Ok think I have sorted it now, change the Zend_Controller_Router_Route as mentioned above and switch the routes around again, i.e. put the artistprofile route before your artistNew route.  That should work, hopefully.

Comment: Hi Garry thanks your last comment worked but I dont wanna have to add all my actions as routes everytime is tthere another work around?

Comment: I don't see the need for using routes in the first place.  You can simply use the url 127.0.0.1/artist/profile/name/somename to view a profile.  The paramater name will contain the artists name which can be read with $this->_request->getParam('name') in your controller.  The URL 127.0.0.1/artist/new can be left to add new artists.

Comment: @Garry I tend to agree with you about routes, but I also understand the desire/need to have certain routes for aesthetic or design purposes. The fix when using named routes is anytime you use a function that can call a route by name you have to pass 'default' if you are not using a name. For example $this->url('controller' => 'index', 'action'=>'index'),'default');